# Exceptions are not getting embedded in DLQ

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-kafka

I have setup a spring cloud stream with kafka binder. I have also enabled the DLQ and have set the headerMode to capture the exception message, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/82). However when there is an exception, I only see the message in my kafka topic without exception details. My application.yml looks like this

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Sample Stream
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      default:
        consumer:
          headerMode: raw
        producer:
          headerMode: raw
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: zookeeper
          brokers: kafka
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: testDLQ
```

I am using version 1.2.1.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka

Answer (score 0):

Kafka (before 0.11) has no support for headers; the kafka11 binder (1.3.x, 2.0.x) could be enhanced to include such information in headers (similar to the rabbit binder `repulishToDlq` option.

I just [opened an issue for this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/228) if you want to follow it.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. I will follow the open issue. One previous [issue] (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/82)  seems to have solved this one but it's not working for me.